# Stacking pages in Umbraco

Tags: razor, umbraco7

In Umbraco you can create doc types that you can also duplicate as a template.

You can then assign Partial views to your template based on your defined doc types.

Does anyone know how you could stack child pages into the master page template?

so if you had 1 master page, you could create child pages and order them as necessary in the master template by using the sorting functionality?

Comment: I am not 100% sure on the requirements, do you mean how to render child pages html inside a parent page?

Comment: Yes, i.e a bit like adding a module to a page.